# Problem with sorting comments in date order

Tags: mysql, sql

I am novice in MySQL and I have a problem with sorting two tables.

This SQL is about sorting newest comments on books, but I am getting these books sorted by first comments on them, not on latest.

```
SELECT b.*, c.date_added as date FROM books b
        LEFT JOIN comments c ON (b.id = c.book_id)
        GROUP BY b.id
        ORDER BY date DESC 
        LIMIT 5

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `caption` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `pages` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `filename` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `description` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `publisher` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `times_sold` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `book_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `author` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `body` text COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `date_added` datetime NOT NULL,
  `approved` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin;
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work out. You are specifying the group on b.id, but since you are multiple comments for each book, you need an aggregate function on c.date_added.  In this case you can use MAX to show the most recent comment date.

```
    SELECT b.*, MAX(c.date_added) as date FROM books b
    LEFT JOIN comments c ON (b.id = c.book_id)
    GROUP BY b.id
    ORDER BY MAX(c.date_added) DESC 
    LIMIT 5
```

Comment: problem is he is also using 'b.*' which means every field in b would have to be aggregated for the query to work.

Comment: Actually, In MySQL that is unnecessary. You can group by whatever you want, but for the columns that aren't in the group by, it will return a random (usually first) result. The nice thing about MySQL is that you only have to group by something that you know to be unique, in this case b.id, and all the other columns in that table just work out.

Comment: The big caveat with that is that in MySQL you have to be really careful with Group By.  In the above query, if you leave out the group by completely, it will return a single row, with the most recent of all comment dates, for all books, but the book information will be for some random (probably first) book record.

Comment: Nope. Since, in my exame, there is no group by, the aggregate function gets the max value across all records.  But for the other columns, it just picks one, again, usually the first. So the comment date and book record wouldn't even be from the same row.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3640/discussion-between-hugh-jones-and-kibbee)

Answer (score 0):

The 'Group By' clause is not correct and you need to remove it.

'Group By' is used for aggregate functions like Min() and Max().

Try This

```
SELECT b.*, c.date_added FROM books b
        JOIN comments c ON  
          c.book_id = b.id
        ORDER BY c.date_added DESC 
        LIMIT 5
```

Comment: having said that I was always trained to avoid using '*' in a select.  It is best practice to list the fields you really want.

Answer (score 0):

There's no field called 'date', you need to order it by date_added (ORDER BY date_added DESC) as it is in your table!
If it's still not in the right order, just use ASC instead of DESC.